# Смена стиля QComboBox qt creator c++

Tags: qt, qtcreator

В процессе тестировки цветового оформления для программы наткнулся на странную деталь: выпадающий список (QComboBox) при смене заднего фона меняется в дизайне (привет Windows XP).

Для сравнения дизайн стандартного ComboBox:
[image: стандартный comboBox]

и ComboBox с измененным цветом заднего фона (с помощью StyleSheet):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вдобавок в измененном варианте comboBox кажется вдавленным. Можно ли как то оставить внешний вид стандартного ComboBox и при этом изменить ему задний фон?

Дополнительно привожу StyleSheet:

> background-color: rgb(255, 109, 108);

Comment: приведите стайлшит

Comment: @SergeyTatarintsev обновил пост